# Printing the final list with for loops (c# help)

Tags: c#

So I have to try to get a specific set of people (values) to print and my input is: 10,2,2,3
The output should be 1,3,7,9
However, I end up getting: 1,5,7
The problem is towards the end of the code, but I am sort of confused what to do about it.

The code:

```
//First Part - Ask user for how many friends there are
Console.WriteLine("How many friends are there in total? [Must Be >= 1 and <= 100]");
string friend = Console.ReadLine();
int AmountOfPeople = Convert.ToInt32(friend);

//Check if the input meets requirements
if (AmountOfPeople < 1 | AmountOfPeople > 100)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is not valid, please restart program.");
}

//Make a list to provide the user with the number of friends coming
List<int> Friends = new List<int>();
int count = AmountOfPeople;
for(int i=1;i<=count;i++)
{
    Friends.Add(i);
}

//Another blank list
List<int> Final = new List<int>();

//Second Part- Ask user how many rounds of removal there will be
Console.WriteLine("How many rounds of removal will there be? [Between 1 and 10]");
string rounds = Console.ReadLine();
int TotalRounds = Convert.ToInt32(rounds);
if (TotalRounds < 1 | TotalRounds > 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is not valid, please restart program.");
}

for (int i = 0; i < TotalRounds; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("What multiple of numbers would you like to remove? [eg. 2,3,4...]");
    string multiple = Console.ReadLine();
    int pick = Convert.ToInt32(multiple);

    foreach (int j in Friends.Reverse<int>())
    {
        if (j % pick == 0)
        {
           Friends.Remove(j);
        }
    }                    
}

Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine("Here are the guests");
Console.WriteLine("");

foreach (int i in Friends)
{      
    Console.WriteLine(i);       
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: First of all, use `||` instead of `|` - that won't check the second condition if the first one passes already.

Comment: Code doesn't compile!!

Comment: You should also really refactor this. the three lines starting with `Console, string, int` are perfect for a method call like `var people = GetNumberFromConsole()`.

Comment: Um it works fine with the | on the c# at school that we use so I'm not quite sure

Comment: @SaltyLegend: Yes, sure, but it is generally more efficient to use the double '||', see short circuit evaluation.

Comment: What are the rules that should be applied to the input?/Why should that specific input give that output? I'm really unsure what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Also the Friends list generation is a one-liner as follows: `var Friends = Enumerable.Range(1, AmountOfPeople).ToList()`.

Comment: Also the writing of the Friends to the console is much easier in one line as `Friends.Select(n => Console.WriteLine(n))`

Comment: First step, separate the input and input validation from the processing. Block comments are a code smell that indicate what should be separate functions. Second step, unit test the processing. It's never too early to learn unit testing. Third step, step through a failing test with the debugger.

Comment: @EluciusFTW Ah okay I see what you are saying

Comment: @SaltyLegend using `|` instead of `||` will cause failures when doing null checks like this: `obj foo = null; if (obj foo == null | foo.bar == null) {do stuff;}`. This will throw a NullReferenceException, because even though you know `foo == null`, it's still trying to evaluate `foo.bar == null`. Using `||` stops the evaluation after the first check that will return `true`

Comment: @tomblodget do you think the suggestion you are making for unit testing is a good suggestion for someone who is just beginning to program? If a person has problems with writing `if` conditions, is it fair to ask them to unit test?

Comment: @saltylegend can you tell us why for `input: 10,2,2,3 The output should be 1,3,7,9`

Comment: @CodingYoshi: Why should it not be `||`?

Comment: @CodingYoshi: And concerning linq: while I might agree with my printing suggestion being a bit unnecessary, the `Friends` initiation is just really painful to my eyes, whether by a beginner or not, so I will suggest linq there for sure.

Comment: For the input 10,2,2,3 the result 1,5,7 is correct. This code will remove first all the even numbers leaving 1,3,5,7,9 at the end of the first loop, then it will remove all numbers multiple of 3 (3 and 9) so the output is 1,5,7. To get your expected result the last input should be 5

Comment: Okay so the 10 = number of guests at start, the 2 = 2 rounds of removal, the next 2 means remove guests by multiples of 2, and then remove by multiples of 3

Comment: http://wcipeg.com/problem/ccc14s1 Here is a link to the direct question itself

Comment: @EluciusFTW my bad about the `||`. You are correct. But i still disagree with using linq. When someone is beginning they need to learn loops etc and only use shortcuts once they have learned the fundamentals.  You are not wrong, but I wouldn't suggest that to a beginner.

Comment: Oh the 2 actually means to remove every 2nd value, and the 3 means to remove every 3rd value. So what would I need to do to change this up? Right now I have it removing by multiples

Comment: While it might seem unimportant at the moment, another small remark: Local variables (like `AmountOfPeople` in your code) should start with a non-capital letter, otherwise it looks like a property of a class name to other people - that'S a .Net convention.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Yes, I do. People learn by reading, copying, and experimenting. Test frameworks can be learned the same way at the same time. Testing gives confidence and supports experimentation. It also promotes refining requirements and concepts, and designing in smaller chunks. Here is an [example](http://share.linqpad.net/pw53qv.linq) that runs in [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/). It includes the given example as a failing integration test.

Comment: @tomblodget so if someone is learning ABCs you would suggest they learn grammar first. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I concur with @Steve that the output is already correct. Here is a solution that I think is a little neater although still needs a little work (Escape condition, exception handling for the parse, or better using tryParse instead).

```
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How many friends are there in total?");
            int amountOfPeople = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (amountOfPeople < 1 || amountOfPeople > 100)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input is not valid");
                continue;
            }

            var friendsList = Enumerable.Range(1, amountOfPeople).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine("How many rounds of removal will there be?");
            int totalRounds = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (amountOfPeople < 1 || amountOfPeople > 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input is not valid");
                continue;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < totalRounds; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Multiples to remove?");
                int pick = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                friendsList.RemoveAll(x => x % pick == 0);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\r\nHere are the guests\r\n");
            friendsList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);                
        }
```

**Also conventions are cool.**

- PascalCasing for class names and method names.
- camelCasing for method
  arguments and local variables.

Comment: May I suggest to refactor the `console.Readline` and input validation to a method call `GetInput(int minValid, int maxValid)`, then the body looks much cleaner.

Comment: wcipeg.com/problem/ccc14s1  

@Dec Yes I thought it was also correct, but I think I have misinterpretted the question and now am a bit confused on what to change.

Comment: I agree @Elucius, i'll edit. Salty - Well,  since you say you now think the output you are getting is correct, you could change nothing, or you could try and take on board some of the concepts in the comments / my answer. They all help.

Comment: @Dec I was solving for every multiple of 2 and 3 will be removed which makes what I did correct, but I think the actual question is saying to remove every 2nd value from the list, then every 3rd value. That would result in 1,3,7,9. *I also put the link up in the comments that shows the actual question as well*

Comment: @Dec good suggestions except for using linq.  `int.Parse` will result in exception if entry is not a number. Use `int.TryParse` method instead.

Comment: Yeah I did mention that at the beginning of my answer